# Opera problems with overlying div element

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with overlapping elements in Opera.
I'm creating an advanced textbox with my own settings but I'm having problems in opera in my html css markup.

this is what I have now

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 200;left: 50px; border: solid 1px black; padding: 3px; width: 200px; height: 30px; border-radius: 2px">
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%">
<span id="placeholder" style="color: grey">placeholder</span>
<div id="input" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

here you can see that I can focus my textbox even when I click on the placeholder which its position is under my editable div. this is how it should be.

problem is in opera. when I click on the placeholder text then my div which is on top is not selected. somehow I'm clicking the underlaying div in opera.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?
I already tried "pointer-events: none" in the placeholder, but this also doesn't work in opera.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: It works just fine for me in Opera 30.0.1835.47.

Comment: hmmm, thats weird. my Opera is updated just a sec ago and its version 12.17

Answer (score 1):

should say thx to Perplexor.

The reason why it didn't work was because of a bug in Opera itself.
I did an update to its latest version but that didn't solve my problem. I had to reinstall the latest version of opera manually and that fixed my problem.